# RJDBC not connecting

Tags: r

I have this code and I get this error 
"Unable to connect JDBC to jdbc:oracle:thin:@//my-host:1505/my-database-name

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath= "C://ORACLE//product//12.1.0//client_2//jdbc//lib//ojdbc7.jar" , " ")
con <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//my-host:1505/my-database-name", "username", "password")
```

any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Try single forward slashes instead of double ones: `classPath= "C:/ORACLE/product/12.1.0/client_2/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar"`, or double back slashes: `"C:\\ORACLE\\product\\12.1.0\\client_2\\jdbc\\lib\\ojdbc7.jar"`

Comment: second line returns "<JDBCDriver>" and third line returns "Error in .verify.JDBC.result(jc, "Unable to connect JDBC to ", url) : 
  Unable to connect JDBC to...."

Comment: when I do single forward or double backslash I still get "JDBCDriver" and the same error message for the 3rd line

Comment: I doubt it will be much help, but when I've connected to databases via java drivers like this before I've done it like so: `drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","/path/to/sqljdbc42.jar");
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://<ipaddress>:<port>;databaseName=<database>;user=<username>;password=<password>")`. The differences here are that the part of the string that says `jdbc:oracle:thin:@` is different to mine, so tinker with slightly. Passing in the username and password as part of the connection string shouldn't make a difference.